# Image - Full Height, Scalable with CSS

Tags: css

I have an image that's tall, but not wide.  I essentially want it to be a full HEIGHT background image (as in, the entire image fills the window from top to bottom) and takes up about 30% of the width of the window.  And I want it to scale accordingly in bigger / smaller windows. (mobile will probably be changed some).

when I experiment with `background-cover`, i find that it makes the image enormous, and in different window sizes, the height of the image gets cut off by the browser window

Comment: What about `background-size: contain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I just figured it out:

```
html { 
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat top left fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
    -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
    -o-background-size: auto 100%;
     background-size: auto 100%;
}
```